# Xamarin error , I set the Target version and Min Version but can't resolve the problem

Tags: xamarin.android

The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for ScratchPad.Android (v8.1) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (9.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for ScratchPad.Android. ScratchPad.Android

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on **Android Project>Properties>Application>Compile using Android version** change this to v9 or above

[image]

Then checking  **Android Manifest>Target Android versions**, same as **Compile using Android version**

[image]

About Android API, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows